# Cant run setDebugModeEnabled on Expo for Firebase Analytics

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-analytics

So to give a little context im using expo-firebase-analytics (latest version)  on Expo (27) and im trying to activate setDebugModeEnabled so that i can use the debugView on firebase analytics.

The problem is that when running it i get the following warning

> The method or property expo-firebase-analytics.setDebugModeEnabled is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]

I havent found any information about it on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i tried to reproduce the issue.It seems ("even though it seemed obvious") that its not available for a reason on ios. but it is in android. if you use an android device it shoudl work seamlesly

Comment: thsnk you so much this didthe job i got an android drvice and its now workingQ

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing the latest version of  expo-firebase-analytics since expo install brings an older one

Comment: Yes i manually installed the latest version thats not the issue apparently.

Answer (score 1):

if you check on the exports is the function there?